# Insert records for 40years in table only date

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to insert only date into a table `MONTH_YEAR` from `01-01-2010` to `01-01-2040`:

For example, I need to insert record on my table month wise
DATE:

```
01-01-2010
01-02-2010
01-03-2010
01-04-2010
01-05-2010
01-06-2010
01-07-2010
01-08-2010
01-09-2010
01-10-2010
01-11-2010
01-12-2010
01-01-2011
01-02-2011
01-03-2011
01-04-2011
01-05-2011
.....................................

01-06-2040
01-07-2040
01-08-2040
01-09-2040
01-10-2040
01-11-2040
01-12-2040
```

Like this I want to insert only date into my table for month wise from `01-01-2010` to `01-01-2040`

Comment: https://blogs.oracle.com/sql/post/how-to-generate-days-weeks-or-months-between-two-dates-in-oracle-database

Comment: That's a recursive query in SQL or a simple loop in PL/SQL. Look them up; its easy.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a hierarchical query:

```sql
INSERT INTO month_year (column_name)
SELECT ADD_MONTHS(DATE '2010-01-01', LEVEL - 1)
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 31*12;
```

Or a recursive query:

```sql
INSERT INTO month_year (column_name)
WITH range (dt) AS (
  SELECT DATE '2010-01-01' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
  SELECT ADD_MONTHS(dt, 1)
  FROM   range
  WHERE  dt < DATE '2040-12-01'
)
SELECT dt FROM range;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=53840fade7fa8df4e8164719c8c1f75e)*

Comment: Perfect !! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Row generator it is:

```
SQL> insert into month_year (datum)
  2  select date '2010-01-01' + level - 1
  3  from dual
  4  connect by level <= date '2040-01-01' - date '2010-01-01' + 1;

10958 rows created.

SQL> select min(datum) min_date,
  2         max(datum) max_date
  3  from month_year;

MIN_DATE   MAX_DATE
---------- ----------
01.01.2010 01.01.2040

SQL>
```

---

If you only need *1st of every month*, then

```
SQL> insert into month_year (datum)
  2  select add_months(date '2010-01-01', level - 1)
  3  from dual
  4  connect by level <= months_between(date '2040-01-01', date '2010-01-01') + 1;

361 rows created.

SQL>
```

Comment: I see that Oracle's `CONNECT BY` performs a hierarchical query - how does it compare to a CTE?

Comment: What kind of a CTE, @Dai?

Comment: Well, what other types of CTE are there for hierarchical or recursive queries besides a recursive CTE?

Comment: I don't know, @Dai. For small data sets, it probably doesn't matter. For example, those 11.000 rows were inserted *instantly*. For larger data sets, one should do some tests.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need 40 years of dates, it seems unlikely or can you make due with a virtual calendar, where you specify a start and end_date and all the dates are generated for you. This example does every day in the range but feel free to modify it to produce what you need. I use it in several places.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE nt_date IS TABLE OF DATE;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION generate_dates_pipelined(
  p_from IN DATE,
  p_to   IN DATE
)
  RETURN nt_date PIPELINED DETERMINISTIC
IS
  v_start DATE := TRUNC(LEAST(p_from, p_to));
  v_end   DATE := TRUNC(GREATEST(p_from, p_to));
BEGIN
  LOOP
    PIPE ROW (v_start);
    EXIT WHEN v_start >= v_end;
    v_start := v_start + INTERVAL '1' DAY;
  END LOOP;
  RETURN;
END generate_dates_pipelined;
/
```